# Regex to filter '*' and '?' special character in yang model

Tags: ietf-netmod-yang

I am trying to create a regex in yang model to not allow * and ? characters. String * and ? should not be allowed as input. 

`.e.g. - abc* - should be okay
      - * - is not okay and should be rejected
Similarly string ("?") should be rejected.`

Tried my hand with regex *'[^*?]+'  which is rejecting any string with any occurrence of * and ?. .e.g abc*, *abc, * and ? all of them are rejected.

Answer (score 1):

YANG uses the XML Schema (XSD) flavor of regular expressions, but this case would be similar in most flavors. If I understand correctly, you wish to prohibit a string to start with characters `*` and `?`.

`[^*?].*`

The above says: the string always has at least one character, where the first character may be any character except `*` or `?` and may be followed by any number of arbitrary characters.

You can read more about the specifics of YANG regular expressions [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/xml.html). Do note that there are subtle differences between regexes defined in different versions of XSD Schema and that YANG relies on the [one](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-2-20041028/#regexs) defined in normative references section of RFC7950 (and RFC6020).