# Yang regex expression

Tags: regex, ietf-netmod-yang

I want to have "YANG" regex expression inputting a string of the format

"c[space or consecutive spaces][character string][space or consecutive spaces]c"

Please let me know the yang regex for this. Please suggest only the "yang" expressions.

example:

```
       "cabdc"

     "c    ab    c"
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. If you are looking for a regular expression that matches your examples, `[cabd ]+` would be one of the many possibilities. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49188838/878469) contains more info on YANG regular expressions.

Comment: @predi i have updated the format.

Comment: `pattern 'c[ ]*[a-zA-Z]+[ ]*c';`. I suggest you read more about regular expressions in general.

Comment: @predi The suggested expression does not work in yang.

Comment: Yes, it does. Why to you think it does not, @Darshan?

Comment: @predi tried the mentioned suggestion and it gave me a  compile error of bad pattern

Comment: your compiler is wrong. You can double check [here](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/) by pasting `<t>cabdc</t>` into left field and `<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:simpleType name="retype">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="c[ ]*[a-zA-Z]+[ ]*c"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:element name="t" type="retype"/>
</xs:schema>` into the right one. Since YANG uses XSD regexes, if it is valid there, it is valid in YANG.

Answer (score 0):

The regular expressions used in yang are similar to the general regular expressions. The keyword in yang for a regex is "pattern".

General example -

```
type xyz {
       pattern '[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,128}';
}
```

As for your question, the answer would be -

```
pattern 'c[ ]{1,}[a-zA-Z]{1,}[ ]{1,}c';
```